# Getting and setting the default Model once another has been setup

Tags: sapui5

My issue is that I have a default model specified in my manifest.json file as "".

However, I'm also setting up a view model in my controller.

```
var oModel = new JSONModel({
            questions: [{
                order: 1,
                title: "",
                criteria: "",
            }]
        });


        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

How do I restore set the view model back to the default model?

Is it simply a case of

```
this.getView().setModel("");
```

I'm asking because the default model is the service that contains all my read/writes.

Comment: with `setModel(oModel, 'myName')` you can have multiple at once.

Comment: setting up this.getView().setModel(oModel,"viewModel"); means I that the properties are no longer available in the view, no matter how I set them up.. {order} , {viewModel>order}  {viewModel>/order>

Comment: i'm also assigning a context to the model - var oContext = oModel.createBindingContext("/questions/0/");
this.getView().setBindingContext(oContext);

Comment: the loop in the table or list is `{viewModel>/questions}`, the attribute in the line is `{viewModel>order}`. Don't set a context on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set named models after setting the default model.So your code should be changed like

```
var oModel = new JSONModel({
        questions: [{
            order: 1,
            title: "",
            criteria: "",
        }]
    });


    this.getView().setModel(oModel,"newModelName");
```

Now you can get default model by

```
this.getView().getModel()
```

and named json model by

```
this.getView().getModel("newModelName");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the way the additional model was initialised and accessed, but naming it and referring to it as 'viewmodel'

This way, the default model can still be setup using

```
    oModel = this.getView().getModel();
```

In the Controller:

```
    this.getView().setModel(oModel,"viewmodel");
    var oContext = oModel.createBindingContext("/questions/0/");
    this.getView().setBindingContext(oContext,"viewmodel");
```

In the view :

```
    title="Question {viewmodel>order}"
```